# Internal server error jdbc when querying a path variable

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, h2, spring-jdbc

I have the code below, and when running I get the following error. There seems to be some kind of issue with `String` to `VARCHAR` conversion.

```
curl -v localhost:8080/trainer/Rach
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /trainer/Rach HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 500
< Content-Type: application/json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Wed, 17 Jun 2020 12:43:21 GMT
< Connection: close
<
{"timestamp":"2020-06-17T12:43:21.205+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT * fr
om TRAINERS where NAME=Rach]; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Column \"RACH\" not found; SQL statement:\nSELECT * from
 TRAINERS where NAME=Rach [42122-200]","path":"/trainer/Rach"}* Closing connection 0
```

#### Controller:

```
 @GetMapping("/trainer/{trainer_name}")
    public Trainer getTrainer(@PathVariable String trainer_name) {
       Trainer t = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT * from TRAINERS where NAME=" + trainer_name , new 
                   TrainerRawMapper());
       return t;
    }
```

#### RawMapper:

```
public class TrainerRawMapper implements RowMapper<Trainer> {
    @Override
    public Trainer mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        Trainer trainer = new Trainer();
        trainer.setName(rs.getString("NAME"));
        trainer.setLevel(rs.getInt("LEVEL"));
        trainer.setBag(new Stack<Pokemon>());

        return trainer;
    }
}
```

#### Sql:

```
CREATE TABLE TRAINERS (NAME VARCHAR(225) PRIMARY KEY,
                        LEVEL INT)
```

```
-- TRAINERS insertions

INSERT INTO TRAINERS (NAME,LEVEL) VALUES ('Rach',8);
INSERT INTO TRAINERS (NAME,LEVEL) VALUES ('Rache',0);
INSERT INTO TRAINERS (NAME,LEVEL) VALUES ('Rachel',1);
INSERT INTO TRAINERS (NAME,LEVEL) VALUES ('Racheli',2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the query and put the `trainer_name` without quotes, like this:

```
String sql = "SELECT * from TRAINERS where NAME = '" + trainer_name +"'";
Trainer t = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new TrainerRawMapper());
```

The solution just to correct what's wrong.

, **For security reason** it's preferred to use a jdbcTemplate to replace values to avoid SQL attacks like SQL injection

```
String sql = "SELECT * from TRAINERS where NAME = ?";
return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{trainer_name}, new TrainerRawMapper());
```

[Spring Doc::queryForObject](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-)

Comment: Never use string concat to build a string, unless you want to be open for SQL injection attacks!.

Comment: Yes, I have mentioned that, thnx

Comment: You might want to use the varargs (see my answer) instead of the older `Object[]` approach.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is you are using String concat to produce a query, this is very dangerous and in this case leads to a wrong query. The values aren't escaped and thus an invalid query. What you should have done is use the proper JDBC mechanisms for replacing values in your query.

```
String query = "SELECT * from TRAINERS where NAME=?"
return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, new TrainerRawMapper(), trainer_name);
```

The query will now be executed properly and you are also safe from SQL Injection attacks. Added benefit the query might now be cached leading to performance gains when being executed again.